# Handlebar function use with dot notation

Tags: spring-boot, mustache, handlebars.java, dot-notation

I am using Handlebars library in my Spring Boot application , and i have a question regarding function call in template
Currently i know that handlebar support function call in [Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) , like this
`{{substring "Hello World!" 6}}`  and it will return string `World!`

But recently i found this page [Jira Smart Values](https://support.atlassian.com/cloud-automation/docs/jira-smart-values-text-fields/) and they are using different approach.

So i want to know how i can achieve the same with handlebar , or if its not possible which library supports that format.

Example from documentation
`{{item.substring(6)}}`  (`item` in this case is also *"Hello World!"*) will also return `World!`